How to View the Request Body (Payload) in Kibana Discover Window?
I'm working with Elasticsearch and Kibana, and everything is functioning as expected. I can see the logs in the Discover window and visualize data effectively. However, I'm struggling to find a way to view the request body (payload) of the requests I send.
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
I want to see the payload of all requests or specific requests.
For example, if I visualize the count of 4XX status codes over time, I want to be able to drill down and see the actual request and its payload at that moment.
I've tried searching for fields like event.original and message, but they don't seem to contain the payload data.
Do I need to make any changes in Elasticsearch or my ELK stack configuration to ensure that the request body is sent to Kibana?
Is there a specific field or setting I might be missing that would allow me to view the request payloads in Kibana?
Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
